# Grey screen in Civilization 6

Tags: kubuntu, games, steam

Hello I had this problem for a while now. Whenever I want to launch the Aspyr version of Civilization VI, everything runs fine, the intro play fine, with music, once the intro is over I am stuck with a plain grey screen, never going away. Civilization 6 worked fine on Windows and on Neon and FerenOS, but for some reason no way to get it working on Ubuntu or Kubuntu. I tried on Ubuntu 18.04 and today I run Kubuntu. Thanks for you help !
PS : I tried running it via the console but it tells me the game needs Steam. No way to get it working, even with Steam logged in and running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem and got here. For me, unsubscribing from the Quick Start Mod (Linux Version, https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1327838427&searchtext=quick) did the trick. Good Luck!